# How to display text output from function in Panel Pyviz widgets?

Tags: panel, ipywidgets, pyviz, holoviz, panel-pyviz

This seems like a basic question but I've tried for a while and not found a solution with Pyviz Panel:

**I'm trying to trigger functions with a click of a button, catch the outputs of functions and print them on the screen at desired locations.**

The `with output` functionality in ipywidgets is a good example of the kind of thing I'm looking to achieve:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

button = widgets.Button(description="Click Me!")
output = widgets.Output()

display(button, output)

def on_button_clicked(b):
    with output:
        print("Button clicked.")

button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
```

However, I can't figure out how to do this with Panel. Here's a simple example of what I'm trying in Pyviz Panel.

```
import panel as pn
pn.extension()
import panel.widgets as pnw

text_output_widget = pnw.StaticText(value='orginal output')
some_button = pnw.Button(name='test',button_type = 'primary')


def callbackfn(WatchedEvents):
    text_output_widget.value = 'new output'
    print('Function successfully run')
    third_party_function() #prints a bunch of stuff


some_button.on_click(callbackfn)
pn.Column(some_button,text_output_widget)
```

However, the output of the `print('Function successfully run')` statement in the `callbackfn()` function gets lost in the process. How do I catch this text output?

**EDIT:**
    Added in a little more detail within the callbackfn function to represent my use case more specifically. I have to run functions (`third_party_function()`) written by people other than me. These functions print stuff, and I can't (not allowed to) change these functions.

Comment: when I put add .show() like this pn.Column(some_button, text_output_widget).show() this will open the browser tab and you can actually see the printout in your jupyter notebook when the button is pushed.

Comment: Is your print function only for checking if your function is finished, so more like logging? Because the callbackfn IS working and changing your text_output_widget.value and this result gets displayed.

Comment: The print function is more of a stand-in for other functions folks in my team have written. 

It's actually going to be more like:


`def callbackfn(WatchedEvents):
           someone_elses_fn()`


and i need to be able to catch that output and pipe it to the correct part of the Panel layout.

Comment: I'm not seeing that when I do .show(). Instead I'm only getting `<bokeh.server.server.Server at 0x7f5f28afd5c0>` printed on my notebook. I think that's because I'm not running Jupyter on my local machine but on a remote server. 

Anyway, not sure how to retrieve the output with .show(). Appreciate the tip though.

Comment: Just wondering: why don't you create another text_output_widget where your write the result to as a variable. Or use something like param: https://panel.holoviz.org/user_guide/Param.html

Comment: Sure. Anything works. But I've just started using Panel and Param. Not sure how I would do that (write the result to a variable). I updated my question to describe my use case more specifically. I'd be grateful if you could give some code example.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `print` statements in your code and see the printed statement in your browser console.
[image: Console output]
You can access the console by right `Ctrl+Shift+I` in Firefox or Chrome.

I was also really frustrated that I could not print anything out to the cell output while using panel. This really limited the debugging ability. Thanks to a user in the Panel Discourse platform for pointing this out to me.